# WebAuthn on Rails via Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, rubygems, webauthn

I have a RoR WebApp which uses **Devise for Authentication**. I stumbled across [FIDO](https://fidoalliance.org/) and specifically [WebAuth](https://webauthn.io/). And now I am trying to implement WebAuthn for the same App. There is a nice gem for implementing WebAuthn on Rails at [web-authn-ruby](https://github.com/cedarcode/webauthn-ruby).

This gem though does not use Devise.
So i wanted to  know what would be the best way to have Devise work with WebAuthn. At a high level, will I have to override Devise's core features and incorporate the WebAuthn methods? Or is there a better alternative?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I reached out to the wonderful team @ [cedarcode.com](https://cedarcode.com) which maintains https://github.com/cedarcode/webauthn-ruby. They are working on the Devise extension for the same and so far its not available. So it seems as of now there are'nt any gems or extension available to do this. But more importantly, the team suggested a separate PR for a different project altogether where they are integrating WebAuth via webauth-ruby gem in a devise based scenario. This is the one
https://github.com/tootsuite/mastodon/pull/14466
This should help anybody interested in integrating WebAuth in their rails project which has devise.

Answer (score 0):

The [webauthn](https://github.com/cedarcode/webauthn-ruby) gem can be integrated with Devise. In a nutshell, you implement webauthn as normal (see their README or their [demo app](https://github.com/cedarcode/webauthn-rails-demo-app) for more information) and then override Devise's default session controller with your own.

In my case I created a session controller under People that inherited from Devise:

```
# app/controllers/people/sessions_controller.rb
class People::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  def new
    # ...
  end

  def create
    # ...
  end
end
```

And then [updated the routes](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/heartcombo/devise/main/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper%3Adevise_for) to tell Devise to use it:

```
# BEFORE
# devise_for :people
# AFTER
devise_for :people, controllers: {sessions: 'people/sessions'}
```

There's an [excellent article](https://www.honeybadger.io/blog/multi-factor-2fa-authentication-rails-webauthn-devise/) from HoneyBadger that goes into a lot more detail.